# Have vs. get in the causative

Tags: meaning, causative-verbs

In causative constructions, for example:

> I'll have him do it for me.
>
> I'll get him to do it for me.

What is the difference in meaning between them?  Obviously, there's a difference in register, with "have" being more formal than get, but I think there's a shade of difference in the actual meaning too.  I'm just finding it hard to pin down.

I have some vague ideas, but I think it would be more productive to leave the conversation open rather than prime it with my own thoughts and end up narrowing the topic.

Feel free to use any example sentences comparing the two verbs, not necessarily the above.

Comment: "Have" gives one a very slight hint that this involves a simple request, while "get" suggests some modest persuasion may be required.  But the difference is minimal -- as much a matter of "tone" and "stiffness", as "get" is a bit more colloquial.

Comment: So if I could ask for more info, I'm wondering if anyone knows why _have_ requires an infinitive without "to" but _get_ requires the to on its following infinitive.

Comment: In causative (causative verb + person/thing + action verb); make (as in force), let (as in allow) and have (as above) take bare infinitives.  All other verbs (e.g. ask, allow, force, require, etc. etc.) take the usual full infinitive.  This isn't an answer "why" as such, but that's the way it works...

Comment: _Get_ has a [special relationship with _have_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/83013/15299), in virtually all of its uses. It's the causative/inchoative of both _have_ and _be_. Given how many idiomatic [constructions _have_ appears in,](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/114942/15299), it's no wonder that [_get_ is a busy verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/104219/15299).

Comment: @Claytonian: like most "why" questions in language, the only answer is "because that's the way it is". Sorry.

Comment: I'll note that "I'll have him do it for me." to my ears is American. I would not use it myself with a specific agent, though I might with an unspecific one: "I'll have them deliver a shed".

Answer (score 1):

There is a degree of force implied in causative verbs. I used to teach them as make, get, have, let, and help in descending degree of persuasion although other grammars teach them as verb patterns and include other verbs. Some only include make, get, and have.
In other words, if I “make SB do STH”, I put a gun to their head. “Have SB do STH” and I probably paid them. “Get SB to do STH” usually means I used some polite persuasion.

Comment: This fits with my intuition. I would add that, to me, "getting" someone to do something implies that I have some sort of active involvement in the process of asking someone to do it. This is rather vague, but it feels more "hands on", in that I imagine I would be asking someone personally to do something.

Having someone do something by contrast feels rather impersonal, almost as if they are doing so as part of their duties. I imagine someone with help in their house "has" the maid make dinner, whereas someone might "get" their brother to give you a lift from the airport.  What do you think?

Comment: @Some_Guy I'm thinking that this wasn't a very well developed answer: there are no links to any reference. You might want to look at John Lawlers's comment posted above and click on his link for a more fully-explained, Other than that, I would say "Go with your intuition"--it sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

The 'have' means we instruct, request or compel someone to do the work, while 'get' means we convince or encourage someone to do the work. Also, 'have' is more formal than 'get'.