# Which of these is right? “I've had three family members recover(ed)”

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

**I've had three family members recover.**

OR

**I've had three family members recovered.**

What's the difference between them (if these both are correct!).

Comment: Were they ill or were they lost at sea?

Comment: Does that matter? Well take both the aspects then!

Comment: Context is important here

Comment: Context always matters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should "Have your peer partner send you her plans" be considered a directive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114935/should-have-your-peer-partner-send-you-her-plans-be-considered-a-directive) John Lawler's answer shows the difference between the merely transpirational  ('This happened to me') sense: (_I had a bird fly in through the open window_) and the causative sense (_I had a man fly across to fix my broken window_).

Answer (score 5):

Both the OP's sentences make syntactical and grammatical sense, but the meanings are different. This is because the meaning of "recover" depends on whether it's being used as a transitive or intransitive verb. (See definitions and plenty of examples of both in the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://https:/https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/recover))

As an intransitive verb, "recover" means to become well (*He recovered from an illness.*), or to return from a negative state to a previous, more positive state (*The economy recovered from its decline.*) This is how the word is used in the first sentence cited by the OP in the question. The family members themselves recovered *from something*.

As a transitive verb, "recover", used with an object, means to get back something one has lost (*We recovered the valuables*, or *After the surprise, he recovered his wits.*). This is how the word is used in the OP's second sentence. The family members were recovered *by someone else* or *by other people*.

So, both constructions can be correct in an appropriate context, but they mean different things.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer so the second use of the verb is transitive. (You had accidentally claimed that both were intransitive.)

Comment: There remains the analysis of the different senses of 'I've had'.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonBassford. Stilly mistake of mine. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

'recover' has (at least) [two similar but distinct meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recover).

One is as an intransitive verb meaning 'to return to a normal condition from a bad one'.

> I've had three family members recover (from an illness).

The other is as a transitive verb meaning 'to receive back, to find something lost'. in the following it is used passively:

> I've had three family members recovered (from the detention center).

So both your examples are correct but for slightly different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Given your examples, I would interpret `recover` as related to a condition - illness, fatigue, etc. `recovered` would be construed as found.

You could probably remove 'have had' as this feels like repetition/tautology.

A simple fix, to help to clarify, would be to add relevant tense and noun:

I have three family members that recovered from cancer.

I have three family members that were recovered from the fire. -- they simply were recovered

I had three family members recovered from the fire. -- you initiated their recovery

Comment: This answer doesn't clarify things at all.

Comment: It's all about the context. However, looking forward to your contribution in an answer to clarify.

Comment: Considering the lack of context in the question, I'd say this clears things up.