# When is 'get' interchangeable with 'be' and do we use 'have' only when it has a causative meaning?

Tags: passive-voice, get-passive

### Get

In **(1)** we can interchange *was* with *get* and thus we have **(2)**. However, this is not only the case as in **(3)**, we cannot use *get* instead of *is*, like in **(4)**. **How can we tell whether is interchangeable or not?**

1. John was fired.
2. John got fired.
3. Robert is liked by everyone.
4. *Robert gets liked by everyone.
5. Fred got his car stolen. **(causative)**

### Have

I've **only** seen *have* been used along with a passive complement, which has a causative meaning. **Is this always the case?**

1. Cecil had his cair repaired by a trustworthy mechanic.
2. I had my car towed away by the police.
3. Susan had Carlos fired.

Comment: Susan didn't cause someone to steal her car.

Comment: @tchrist I know, but it's correct.

Comment: It's not a causative use.

Comment: @thcrist Similar to "I've had my bag stolen"

Comment: You didn't make somebody steal your bag. These are not causatives.

Comment: @thrcrist "This structure can also be used to refer to things that other people did/have done to us but which we didn't ask them to do, for example, stealing something of ours."

Comment: [OED *have* sense 29b](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/84705#eid1807741) covers this case. As you can see from their text, this use of *have* with a participle complement is not a causative and it is not even a passive: it's transitive. It is an alternative to an indirect passive, especially for ditransitives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126058/discussion-between-nameless-and-tchrist).

Comment: *Cecil had* is causative but not passive in *Cecil had his car repaired by a trustworthy mechanic.* The passive part is *his car repaired by...* In the active voice that would be: *Cecil had a trustworthy mechanic repair his car.* Here is *had* in the passive voice: *A good time was had by all.*

Comment: @TInfoilHat Is the whole sentence not considered passive then?

Comment: @TinfoilHat The whole sentence is considered causative?

Comment: No. Both sentences start with the subject + causative verb *Cecil had*, so you could call both sentences active — and causative —  in their entirety.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Active even though it has a passive clause?

Comment: Yes. A sentence's passive clause doesn't necessarily condemn the whole sentence to being passive.

Comment: Try these substitute meanings for get: arrive [here/there], receive, become, earn, win., buy, purchase, understand.  There are others I just can't think of them now. And get + part participle: result in the condition of being something: get fired, get tired, get promoted.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any rule for *get* being interchangeable with *be*. *Get* is already in a paradigm with *be*.
As well as with *have*.

[*Get*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104219/15299) is an auxiliary verb, and it functions as the [inchoative/causative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/547059/15299) form of **both** the auxiliary verb *be* **and** the auxiliary verb *have*.

- *Bill has the flu. ~ Bill got the flu*. (inchoative of *have*)
- *Bill is sick. ~ Bill got sick*. (inchoative of *be*)
- *Bill has a car. ~ Bill got a car*. (causative of *have*)

So it's not interchangeable with either *be* or *have*, but when dealing with persistent predicates changes in the past affect the present and future. If Bill got a car last year, chances are he still has it. If he got sick last week, he may still be sick.

So they **look** like they're interchangeable, but that's not the way things work. Nothing is interchangeable. Sentence grammar is not a matter of adding words like beads on a string, changing them at will. But it's not a box of beads; it's more like a junk drawer of mismatched screws, bolts, and hinges that will miraculously fit together at speed (if you use the right tools to assemble them and don't put them under too much stress).

[There are also](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114942/15299) at least adversative and causative *have* constructions, with or without Raising.

Comment: Well, you can do an English-to-English translation to see a meaning for get.....